# CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VpcId] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am working with multiple CF templates, and intend to export and import values across the templates. I exported/imported most values fine, however run into this problem where VpcId is not being imported for some reason.

First template with export

```
Parameters:
  StackPrefix:
    Type: String
    Default: "app-name"

Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Join [ ":", [ !Ref StackPrefix, VPC ] ]
```

Second template with import

```
Parameters:
  StackPrefix:
    Type: String
    Default: "app-name"

Resources:
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-alb
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          IpProtocol: "TCP"
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${StackPrefix}:VPC"
```

Deploying the template with `aws cli` results in a "template validation error"

`aws --profile shiny-app cloudformation create-stack --stack-name app-elb --template-body file://02-load-balancer.yaml`

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VpcId] in the Resources block of the template
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else in the template somewhere causing this issue? Just to test, remove the import from the VpcID and hardcode the VPC ID. Can you also confirm that the VpcID is in fact exporting correctly from the 1st stack?

Comment: I am not sure you are pointing at the cuprit.  Do you have a `!Ref: VpcId` somewhere?

Also, for debugging you first stack, you should be able to see the Export Name in the Outputs tab of the CloudFormation console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the AWS console if the output of your first stack is correct else try with:

```
!Sub '${AWS::StackName}:VPC'
```

You don't need add a prefix parameter in the first stack just use the name, then try something like this in your second stack at line 53, and add the parameter ParentVPCStack with the name of your first stack.

```
 VpcId: {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}:VPC'}
```

For me this works.

Answer (score 1):

After a sleepless night, and running past a colleague I wish to answer my own question

@Seth E thanks for the input, you're right on the money.

I had this in lines 53-54

```
 53       VpcId:
 54         Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${StackPrefix}:VPC"
```

...and in line 117 this came out

```
117       VpcId: !Ref VpcId
```

I think CloudFormation for the most part helps to identify which line in the template has the offending code, for this mistake however CloudFormation wasn't clear enough to me. Debugging in CF (outputting values isn't as straight forward), I think this is something I'll need to get used to debugging CF templates.

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VpcId] in the Resources block of the template
```